# Python creating thread in function

Tags: python, multithreading, java-threads

I am learning how to start a thread in Python but am having trouble understanding how to go about it since I have only learned threads in Java and it seems drastically different in terms of syntax.

I am trying to wrap my head around how to approach it.

I want to do something like this in Python

```
 Runnable runIt = new Runnable() {
 ....
 public void run() {
 ....
 }
}
runThread.start();
```

What is the best approach to do this in Python?

Comment: Read the threading module documentation.  What doesn’t work for you? Show code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Java, Python threads are just functions and arguments.  Things do not need to be wrapped inside `Runnable`.

```
from threading import Thread

def foobar(x, y):
    print(x + y)

thread = Thread(target=foobar, args=(1, 3))
thread.start()
thread.join()
```

I highly recommend you do not use threads directly, but instead use one of the higher level packages.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. Could you explain why to use the higher level packages?

Comment: If you've read Josh Bloch's Effective Java (highly recommended), you'll know that he recommends *not* using threads, but instead using higher level constructs such as Executors, Tasks, and streams.  The same applies in Python.  ThreadPoolExecutor and ThreadPool take care of a lot of the bookkeeping for you.